# search unique element pairs and transform sorted result to JSON

Tags: json, nosql

I have below sample input: (They are individual documents)

```
    <performance>
        <year>2016</year>
        <industry>Financials</industry>
        <benchmark>Healthcare</benchmark>
</performance>
 
    <performance>
        <year>2017</year>
        <industry>Technology</industry>
        <benchmark>Financials</benchmark>
</performance>
 
    <performance>
        <year>2018</year>
        <industry>Technology</industry>
        <benchmark>Financials</benchmark>
</performance>
 
    <performance>
        <year>2019</year>
        <industry>Financials</industry>
        <benchmark>Materials</benchmark>
</performance>
 
    <performance>
        <year>2020</year>
        <industry>Technology</industry>
        <benchmark>Materials</benchmark>
</performance>
 
    <performance>
        <year>2021</year> 
        <industry>Technology</industry>
        <benchmark>Healthcare</benchmark>
  </performance>
```

I need to find the industry and benchmark pairs, sort the result document on year, and finally transform the pairs to JSON. I would like to use Marklogic’s index to speed up search and transform. The expected output is:

```
  {
    "Financials": [
"Materials", 
"Healthcare"
    ], 
    "Technology": [
"Healthcare", 
"Materials", 
"Financials"
    ]
 }
```

My Xquery code:

```
let $keys := ('Financials', 'Technology')
let $map := map:map()
let $_ :=
  for $key in $keys
  let $query :=  cts:path-range-query("/performance/industry", "=", $key)
  let $v :=  cts:values(cts:path-reference('/performance/benchmark'), (), (), $query)
  return map:put($map, $key, $v)
return xdmp:to-json($map)
```

Unexpected output:

```
{
"Financials":[
  "Healthcare", 
  "Materials"
], 
"Technology":[
  "Financials", 
  "Healthcare", 
  "Materials"
]
}
```

Do I use Xquery in the wrong way or misunderstand how the Marklogic index works? How can I get the correct output? I am fine with Javascript or Xquery.

Comment: You want the values in the array sorted by the year within the document? What if there are multiple docs with the same industry and benchmark with different years? How many docs are you dealing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you put a sequence of values in the map, they wind up being sorted.

With this solution, I fetch all of the `benchmark` and `year` for each `industry`, sort the values in `descending` order by `year`, dedup with `distinct-values()` and then put them into an `array-object()` in order to maintain the sorted order.

```
let $map := map:map()
let $industries := ('Financials', 'Technology')
let $_ :=
  for $industry in $industries
  let $query :=  cts:path-range-query("/performance/industry", "=", $industry)
  let $tuples := cts:value-tuples((cts:path-reference('/performance/benchmark'), cts:path-reference('/performance/year')), (), $query)
  let $sorted-values :=
    for $tuple in $tuples
    let $benchmark := $tuple[1]
    let $year := $tuple[2]
    order by $year descending
    return $benchmark
  return map:put($map, $industry, array-node{ distinct-values($sorted-values) })
return xdmp:to-json($map)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mads Hansen!  It transforms the XML. So we are looking at `sort` with `cts:index-order` or inner `cts:value-tuples` to speed up. Any thought?